# Prove that $\phi_{2n}(X)=\phi_n(-X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Cyclotomic polynomials satisfy $x^n-1=\prod_{n_1|n}\phi_{n_1}(X)$

> Prove that $\phi_{2n}(X)=\phi_n(-X)$

I need to be able to show that: $\zeta$ is an $n$-th primitive root of unity then $-\zeta$ is a $2n$-th root of unity

Let: $2n=p_1p_2..p_k$ and $n=p_1p_2..p_k$

Using the above formula for each case:

$$x^{2n}-1=\phi_{2}(X)\phi_{p_1}(X)...\phi_{p_k}(X)\phi_{2n}(X)$$

$$x^{n}-1=\phi_{p_1}(X)...\phi_{p_k}(X)\phi_{n}(X)$$

So $\phi_{2n}(X)=\frac{x^{2n}-1}{\phi_{2}(X)\phi_{p_1}(X)...\phi_{p_k}(X)}$ and $\phi_{n}(X)=\frac{x^{n}-1}{\phi_{p_1}(X)...\phi_{p_k}(X)}$

So $\phi_{n}(-X)=\frac{-x^{n}-1}{\phi_{p_1}(-X)...\phi_{p_k}(-X)}$

I cannot see how $\phi_{2n}(X)=\phi_n(-X)$ from here. I tried to think instead in terms of $\zeta$ and $-\zeta$ but I am unsure

Could someone help me prove this?

---

Also, say we want to find the cyclotomic polynomial when $n$ is large and even, is using the above identity the best way to calculate it? For example, say we wanted to find $\phi_{50}(X)$, would we first calculate $\phi_{25}(X)$, or is there a quicker way?

Comment: if $n$ is odd : $x^{2n}-1 = \prod_{ d | 2n} \phi_d(X) =\prod_{ d | n}\phi_d(X)\phi_{2d}(X)$

Comment: and what you wrote is suspect : there more divisors than just $\phi_{p_k}(X)$. the divisors of $30$ are $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$.. and are you allowed to use $\phi_n(x) =
\prod_\stackrel{1\le k\le n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}
\left(x-e^{2i\pi\frac{k}{n}}\right)$ ?

Comment: What you're trying to prove is false when $n$ is even, so you need to assume that $n$ is odd.

Comment: @GregMartin : and [there is the particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Examples) case $n=1$